# Resizing columns without overflow

Tags: css, css-grid

I want my embedded columns to be first start with 50/50 spacing, and then to be able to resize them without overflowing the column that contains them.

What I'm getting is initial columns that are approximately 20/80, and when I resize the right column bleeds outside its enclosing column until if reaches its minimum.

```css
body {
  margin: 10px;
}

wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  grid-template-columns: [col] 50px [col] minmax(200px, 1fr) [col] minmax(200px, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: [row] 50px [row] minmax(250px, 1fr) [row] 25px;
  width: 96vw;
  height: 96vh;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
}

header {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 80%;
  grid-column: col / span 3;
  grid-row: row;
}

tail {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 80%;
  grid-column: col 2 / span 2;
  grid-row: row 3 / span 2;
}

mode {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 80%;
  grid-column: col;
  grid-row: row 2 / span 3;
}

data {
  grid-column: col 2 / span 2;
  grid-row: row 2;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  grid-template: "left right" 1fr / min-content 1fr;
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 80%;
}

primary {
  grid-area: left;
  overflow: auto;
  min-width: 120px;
  max-width: 80vw;
  resize: horizontal;
  background-color: #ccc;
  color: #444;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 100%;
}

secondary {
  grid-area: right;
  overflow: auto;
  min-width: 120px;
  max-width: 80vw;
  background-color: #ccc;
  color: #444;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 100%;
}
```

```html
<wrapper>
  <header>header</header>
  <mode>mode</mode>
  <data>
        <primary>primary data</primary>
        <secondary>secondary data</secondary>
    </data>
  <tail>tail</tail>
</wrapper>
```

Answer (score 0):

> What I'm getting is initial columns that are approximately 20/80...

That seems to be what you defined for your columns:

```
data {
    display: grid;
    grid-template: "left right" 1fr / min-content 1fr;
}
```

The final two values in `grid-template` represent column sizes.

If you want two columns 50/50, try this instead:

```
data {
    display: grid;
    grid-template: "left right" 1fr / 1fr 1fr;
}
```

> ... and when I resize the right column bleeds outside its enclosing column until if reaches its minimum.

Well, you have minimum widths set.

200px minimums on the last two columns in your outer grid:

```
wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: [col] 50px [col] minmax(200px,1fr) [col] minmax(200px,1fr);
}
```

120px minimums on your grid areas in your nested grid:

```
primary {
    grid-area: left;
    min-width: 120px;
}

secondary {
    grid-area: right;
    min-width: 120px;
}
```

Where do you expect them to overflow?

Comment: Ok, so the 1fr replacement I totally get.

Comment: Where do you expect them to overflow?  I'm not talking about CSS overflow, its the interior column bleeding outside the exterior column that is the problem.

Comment: Not sure I see what you're talking about. Can you add more details or post an image of the problem in your question? Thanks.

Comment: The bleeding is no longer an issue, but now the primary column is locked a 50%.  See https://codepen.io/dacracot/pen/JVpMEm.

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying. You want the both columns to max out at 50%, and the first one to re-size down to min-content. Not sure it's possible with Grid. Try working with percentage units, `auto` and `minmax()`.

Comment: I want them both to size down to min-content, but start at 50%.

Comment: `data {  grid-template: "left right" 1fr / minmax(min-content, 50%) minmax(min-content, 50%); }` ?